# Replace an element but preserve all element data

Tags: javascript, html

I need to somehow replace an element in the DOM, but make the new element contain all the data the original had (attributes, event listeners, properties). This needs to be done in vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery, etc) and I can't control the HTML.

My current approach was to use `element.replaceWith()` and reassign attributes with a `for` loop.
However, this only copied attributes and I also need to preserve event listeners.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#elem');

function changeElem() {
  let e=document.createElement('textarea');
  for(let i of el.attributes)
    e.setAttribute(i.name,i.value);
  
  el.replaceWith(e);
  el=e;
}

el.addEventListener('keyup', evt => {
  if(evt.code=='KeyM')alert('Key M pressed!');
})
```

```html
Try to press <b>M</b> to check if event listeners are attached:
<br>
<input id="elem" type="text" value="Some value">
<br>
<button onclick="changeElem()">Click to replace</button>
```

When event listeners have been assigned by setting `el.onkeyup` it works, but with `el.addEventListener()` it doesn't.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it your code that is creating the `addEventListener`s? If so you can try delegating it to the body instead of the element itself.

Comment: @imvain2 No, It's not my code.